# Input in the Groovy parameters to output as a json

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to setupa Jenkins/Groovy setup where we input certain va;ues to our Jenkins pipeline, I am trying my Groovy to output as a json.
My current script is as shown below:

```
    parameters([
        choice(name: "Environment", choices: ['Dev', 'QA', 'PRD'], description: 'Select Env', required: true),
        choice(name: 'Select Type', choices: ['EC2', 'EKS', 'ECS'], description: 'Select type'),
        choice(name: 'permission', choices: ['user', 'service account', 'policy'], description: 'Select permission'),
        string(name: "TeamDL", description: 'Provide Team Name', required: true),
        string(name: "ProductType", description: 'Enter the product name', required: true),
        string(name: 'TeamWork', description: 'Provide team DL', required: true),
    ])
```

I am looking for the Groovy Logic if users input certain values into these choice/string fields, my output to be:

```
{
"environment": "Dev",
"Select Type": "ECS",
"Permission": "service account",
"teDL": "teamdl@yahoo.com",
"producttype": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"TeamWork": "sucks"
}
```

Any inputs on how to set up my login in Groovy so the output can be a json with the filled in fields??

Cheers!!

Jenkins/Groovy output a json values

Answer (score 0):

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters

The parameters directive provides a list of parameters that a user should provide when triggering the Pipeline. The values for these user-specified parameters are made available to Pipeline steps via the `params` object.

so, i theory this should work to get params as json:

```
def paramsJson =  writeJSON returnText: true, json: params
```

Comment: Sure. Does this params need to be tagged as a stage or just need to be incorporated within the main script?

Comment: it should be a part of a script

Comment: Ok, I added a stage for the same and the output came empty. There was no JSON associated output from the job.
Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: could you provide in question more then parameters declaration? could you test result for following statements: `echo "ProductType = ${params.ProductType}"` and `echo "params = ${params}"`

Comment: Hello ,I got the solution here (with a help of a co-worker): We used a function to output the params data with this syntax:

  { def paramsJson =  writeJSON returnText: true, json: params
                     logUtils.printNicePhaseOutputToLog ("$paramsJson") }

And it worked. Appreciate the response pal.